# Anki: Why do learning cards change category when you bury them?

Tags: anki

I am learning how to use Anki to study Japanese. In the manual, it says:

> " If cards were in learning when they are buried, they are moved back to the new card queue or review queue prior to being buried. "

Why does burying learning cards cause them to move to the new or learned categories? There doesn't seem to be an explanation online for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, cards are generally buried when you have a reverse of that same card. For example, if you have a Japanese-to-English card and *also* an English-to-Japanese card of the same vocab word, it makes sense for Anki to bury that card for that day. This is helpful because it means you're not testing yourself on what's essentially the same thing in the same day (instead, it moves to tomorrow's queue so you're testing yourself on "new" content). I hope that helps!